# Redis with nginx call back configuration

Tags: php, nginx, lua, redis

I am trying to config my nginx with redis. I want nginx to check redis cache key if it exists then return it as a response. Else call URL and create redis cache key and return response. For this, I m using resty-redis nginx addon.

Here is my nginx configuration. I am little confused how to make the call if the cache is not available in redis.

```
init_by_lua 'initCall = 1';
server {
listen 80;

access_log /var/log/nginx/accessapill.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/errorapill.log;

root /var/www/html/api/api;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

charset utf-8;
charset_types application/json;
default_type application/json;

server_name apill.com;

location / {
        content_by_lua_block {
            if (initCall == 1) then
                initCall = 0
                local args = ngx.req.get_uri_args()
                local keyset={}
                local n=0
                for key, val in pairs(args) do
                     n=n+1
                     keyset[n]=key.."="..val
                end
                --ngx.say("/readRedis" .. ngx.var.uri .. "?" .. table.concat(keyset, "&"))
                local response = ngx.location.capture("/readRedis" .. ngx.var.uri .. "?" .. table.concat(keyset, "&"))
                ngx.say(table.concat(response,""))
            end
        }

    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location /readRedis {
    content_by_lua_block {
        local redis = require "resty.redis"
        local red = redis:new()
        local ok, err = red:connect("127.0.0.1", 6379)
        red:set_timeout(1000) -- 1 sec
        local calledUrl = ngx.var.uri
        calledUrl = calledUrl.gsub("/readRedis", "")
        local args = ngx.req.get_uri_args()
        local keyset={}
        local n=0
        for key, val in pairs(args) do
             n=n+1
             keyset[n]=key.."="..val
        end
        calledUrl = calledUrl .. "?" .. table.concat(keyset, "&");
        local keyVal, err = red:get(ngx.md5(calledUrl))
        if not(keyVal == nil) and (#keyVal > 0) then
            ngx.say(keyVal)
        else
            calledUrl = "/fallback" .. calledUrl .. "?" .. table.concat(keyset, "&")
            local response = ngx.location.capture(calledUrl)
            red:set(ngx.md5(calledUrl), response)
            red:expire(ngx.md5(calledUrl), 3600)
            ngx.say(response)
        end
    }
}

location /hello {
    content_by_lua_block {
        local args = ngx.req.get_uri_args()
        local keyset={}
        local n=0
        for key, val in pairs(args) do
                     n=n+1
                     keyset[n]=key.."="..val
        end
        ngx.say("/readRedis" .. ngx.var.uri .. "?" .. table.concat(keyset, "&"))
    }
}

location /fallback {
    resolver 127.0.0.1;
    if ($request_uri ~* "/fallback/(.*)") {
        proxy_pass  http://apill.com$1;
    }
}


location ~ \.php$ {
    root /var/www/html/api/api;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/html/api/api/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#
#   # With php5-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php5-fpm:
#   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
#}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? From a quick glance it all seems to do as it should.

Comment: Thanks for response.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Actually, the problem is I am not able to create cache when it does not exist in redis.

If cache key does not exist then script need to call that URL and create cache key with the response.

I hope I can communicate properly my problem.

Thanks in advance for helping me in this.